# Trouble understanding the definition of winding number

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

I do understand what the winding number is visually, but I am a little bit confused about its definition.

Let $\gamma :[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a closed curve, $p \notin trace(\gamma)$ and  let $\Theta_p$ be the angle of the curve $\gamma_p(t):=\gamma(t)-p$.

Then we call $Wind(\gamma,p):=\frac{\Theta_p(b)-\theta_p(a)}{2 \pi}$.

I don't really understand why we shift $\gamma$ to get $\gamma_p$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: I'm assuming there's a typo and you intend $\gamma$ to parametrize a curve in the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Think of a lighthouse at $p$ tracing the point $\gamma(t)$ as it moves around. Then $\gamma_p(t)$ is the radial vector from $p$ to $\gamma(t)$, and the winding number is counting the net number of times that it travels around $p$.

The shift $\mathbf{x} \mapsto \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{p}$ sends the point $\mathbf{p}$ to the origin, and so $\gamma_p$ can be interpreted as points with respect to this *new* origin, in addition to being the displacement vector from $p$ to $\gamma(t)$.